# Why won't this variable display its number in its innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

This is part of a basic rock paper scissors game. I declared a few counter variables that increase as each click on an option executes. When I console.log the score values, they do increase, but the innerHTML won't display that increase. I do not think I am declaring the innerHTML as the variable correctly. (Also, the HTML is correct because any other string in the innerHTML declaration works.)

```
var playerscore = 0;
var computerscore = 0;

document.getElementById('cpuscore').innerHTML = computerscore;
document.getElementById('playerscore').innerHTML = playerscore;



rock.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let computerSelection = computerPlay();
  let game = playRound(computerSelection, 'Rock');
    if (game === 'tie') {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Tie!';
  } else if (game === 'player') {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'You win!';
        playerscore++;
  } else {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'You lose!';
      computerscore++;
  }
  }
);
```

Comment: In JavaScript, an assignment with `=` does not establish a permanent relationship.

Comment: Are you sure that this part of the code has issues because I see some of the variables and methods which are not declared but used such as `rock` and `customPlay()`?  Please add necessary code

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `innerHTML` whenever you update the variable. They're not automatically sync'ed.

```js
rock.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let computerSelection = computerPlay();
  let game = playRound(computerSelection, 'Rock');
  if (game === 'tie') {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Tie!';
  } else if (game === 'player') {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'You win!';
    playerscore++;
    document.getElementById('playerscore').innerHTML = playerscore;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'You lose!';
    computerscore++;
    document.getElementById('cpuscore').innerHTML = computerscore;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i understand and appreciate it!

Comment: @Vigz If this answer resolved your issue, you should [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it. This helps future readers that might have a similar problem find the right solution for them faster. Once you gain a little more [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [up-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) answers you find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the assignment operator to set the innerHTML of a DOM element, it's simply a one-time update. It does not cause the innerHTML to reference a value which can be updated. So in addition to setting the innerHTML to the scores at the beginning, you will have to do it every time the scores change.

As an aside, you may have thought otherwise from having had interaction with many modern reactive frameworks that abstract this away and do it for you through a Virtual DOM generating view-function

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful, I'm extremely new, hence the rock paper scissors game. But, I understand

Answer (score 0):

If you want the page to show the new scores every time they are changed, you'll need to update the DOM every time you change the scores. In other words, put your `...innerHTML = {score}` code inside your event handler.

Here's a quick demo:

```js
var playerscore = 0;
var computerscore = 0;

// display initial scores
document.getElementById('cpuscore').innerHTML = computerscore;
document.getElementById('playerscore').innerHTML = playerscore;

document.getElementById('run').addEventListener("click", function() {
  // ... game logic here ...
  if (Math.random() > .5)
    computerscore++
  else
    playerscore++;
  
  // display updated scores
  document.getElementById('cpuscore').innerHTML = computerscore;
  document.getElementById('playerscore').innerHTML = playerscore;
});
```

```html
<div>CPU Score: <span id="cpuscore"></span></div>
<div>Player Score: <span id="playerscore"></span></div>

<button id="run">Run</button>
```